# Filter QGraphicsItems type in a scene from items()

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I'm looking for a way to get all the QGraphicsLineItem from a scene, using items().

It gives a list of all the QGraphicsItem, but I want to perform actions only on QGraphicsLine for example. How can I sort this list/extract the items I want with a specific type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the list and test the type with a `dynamic_cast`:

```
// I'm not sure where you want to implement this,
// but it can be in your derived GraphicsScene class.
// Else, just call scene->items() and make a new list
// outside of the scene class.
void CustomScene::foo()
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> itemList = items();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); ++i) {
         if (auto lineItem{dynamic_cast<QGraphicsLineItem*>(itemList[i])})
             // do a specific action or put this in a QList of QGraphicsLiteItem*s
             // and return that list instead of void
             ;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but something like this should be possible.

Comment: Thanks, is already helps me a lot I tested it to remove all Lines ! Just change to 'dynamic_cast<QGraphicsLineItem*>'

Comment: Woops, sorry :P Also, You can of course modify the `QList` that `items()` returned, but it's much easier (for you) and more bug free to make a new one and add all the `QGraphicsLineItem*` to that one. This way you can be sure you aren't accidentally skipping elements in the returned list you're looping over. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

Also to check item type it will be faster to use `qgraphicsitem_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` because `qgraphicsitem_cast` uses `static_cast` under the hood.